# Trying to switch editor input from within setInput()

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor

I have an Eclipse editor that modifies multiple files. When there is an error in any one of these files, I want it to open MyEditor instead of the standard text editor that it might otherwise open.

I forced the marker to open MyEditor by setting the marker attribute:

```java
marker.setAttribute(IDE.EDITOR_ID_ATTR, "com.example.xyz.MyEditorID");
```

Now, within `MyEditor.setInput()`, I have the following code to switch the input from the incoming file to the main file:

```java
    protected void setInput(final IEditorInput input) {
        FileEditorInput fileEditorInput = (FileEditorInput) input; 
        final IFile file = (IFile) input.getAdapter(IFile.class);
        if( file.getName().endsWith(mySuffix) ) {
        // this is a coded values type file. It needs to be opened with the default profile
            fileEditorInput = new FileEditorInput(theCorrectFileName);
        }
        ... 
        super.setInput(fileEditorInput);
        ...
    }
```

I changed the Editor's equals method to return true if the inputs are equal

```java
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if(obj == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if(this == obj) {
        return true;
    }

    if( !getClass().isInstance(obj) ) {
        return false;
    }
    final MyEdior otherEditor = (MyEditor) obj;
    return getEditorInput().equals( otherEditor.getEditorInput() );
}
```

But when I click on my error marker, it *still* opens up a new editor every time. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `equals` method is not used to match the editor to the editor input. Instead you need to use an `IEditorMatchingStrategy` class to match your editor to the input.

You specify this class on your `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point using the `matchingStrategy` attribute.

For example, this is the Manifest.mf / plugin.xml / build.properties editor:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
  <editor
        default="true"
        name="%editors.pluginManifest.name"
        icon="$nl$/icons/obj16/plugin_mf_obj.gif"
        class="org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.editor.plugin.ManifestEditor"
        contributorClass="org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.editor.plugin.ManifestEditorContributor"
        matchingStrategy="org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.editor.plugin.ManifestEditorMatchingStrategy"
        id="org.eclipse.pde.ui.manifestEditor">
        <contentTypeBinding contentTypeId="org.eclipse.pde.pluginManifest"/>
        <contentTypeBinding contentTypeId="org.eclipse.pde.fragmentManifest"/>
        <contentTypeBinding contentTypeId="org.eclipse.pde.bundleManifest"/>            
  </editor>
```

The matching strategy just has the one method to match a editor reference to the input:

```java
public boolean matches(IEditorReference editorRef, IEditorInput input)
```

All this is intended for editors (such as the Manifest.mf editor) which edit several files at once, but I think you may be able to use it.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Again. I'm not sure how my project would be going without your help.